# Recreate Github's responsive logos' showcase

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

### Explanation

I'm trying to recreate the logo showcase on the bottom of [Github's site](https://github.com) (it only appears if signed off). When inspecting it, the logos' size changes based on the screen resolution (as you can see below), but in my code (which I tried to do the most similar to Github's) nothing happens; it stays the same size for every resolution.

[image]

### Code

As I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.7, which doesn't support flexbox (at least it didn't work when writing the specific css as html classes), I had to write the css.

You can also see it in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jsbsz63q/) and in ["fullscreen mode"](http://jsfiddle.net/jsbsz63q/embedded/result/).

```css
.logos {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    padding: 0;
}

.logos .text-center {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
}

.logos ul {
    text-align: center;
    filter: grayscale() !important;
    display: flex !important;
    list-style: none;
    -webkit-box-pack: center !important;
    justify-content: center !important;
    flex-wrap: wrap !important;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-top: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.logos li {
    display: list-item;
    text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.logos .logo-img {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: auto;
    margin: 10px 20px;
    padding-right: 0 !important;
    padding-left: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <section class="logos">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="text-center">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#"><img class="logo-img" src="http://i.imgur.com/UPabVoZ.png" alt=""></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><img class="logo-img" src="http://i.imgur.com/UPabVoZ.png" alt=""></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><img class="logo-img" src="http://i.imgur.com/sT2RPP2.png" alt=""></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><img class="logo-img" src="http://i.imgur.com/UPabVoZ.png" alt=""></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><img class="logo-img" src="http://i.imgur.com/sT2RPP2.png" alt=""></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js" integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance,
Luiz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using media queries to help size the images at specific screen sizes. Here's an example:

CSS

```
@media (max-width: 768px /* Or whatever you want */) {
   .logos .logo-image {
      width: 100px; /* Once again, whatever you want */
   }
}
```

Here's a link that explains media queries: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you!! But I don't think it is what happens in Github's site (at least I didn't find anything about it). I don't know if it is something like Bootstrap's `img-responsive` (already tried this one; nothing happens) or another Bootstrap's class (since it was also rebuilt by one of Bootstrap's founders, I think) or even no Bootstrap at all.

Comment: No problem! Using `.img-responsive` won't work because you have the images set to `inline-block`. However, this class uses `display: block`. I think Github is using flexbox. But, you don't want to use that, right? Thus, I would still recommend using media queries. Hope this helps!

Comment: No, no, sorry! You might've misunderstood. I have no problem in using flexbox, the only thing is that I can't use as Bootstrap class, since it isn't supported in 3.3.7 (it is on Bootstrap 4, but it is on alpha yet).

Comment: Oh, cool. Then, you can always use flexbox instead if you want.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to answer. I read, once again, this part of Github's code and see that they actually used media queries to do it. Thank you for your answer!!

Comment: No  problem! Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the picture-element. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture)

Comment: I updated in another [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/otffwju6/), but nothing happened.

Answer (score 1):

First of all get rid of all that bootstrap because it's ugly and confusing, you can get rid of 3 extra container divs without it, and it doesn't support flexbox yet apparently? (Bootstrap 4 is supposed to use it if that is out, I don't know because I prefer not to use Bootstrap if you couldn't tell)
Then use flexbox and set the img to have `max-width: 100%;` to maintain aspect ratio. Mess around with the `justify-content` as needed:

```css
.logos {
  dislay: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.top-logos {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.bottom-logos {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="logos">
  <div class="top-logos">
    <a href="#"><img class="logo-img large" src="http://i.imgur.com/UPabVoZ.png" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="logo-img large" src="http://i.imgur.com/UPabVoZ.png" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="logo-img small" src="http://i.imgur.com/sT2RPP2.png" alt=""></a>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom-logos">
    <a href="#"><img class="logo-img large" src="http://i.imgur.com/UPabVoZ.png" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="logo-img small" src="http://i.imgur.com/sT2RPP2.png" alt=""></a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you!! It worked, but in order to keep all images in one row. I'd like it to wrap like this logo's section in Github's site. I tried to set `flex-wrap: wrap;
` (as Github's code), but then the resizing doesn't work.